# Cannot convert value of type '[String : String?]' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to add some user data into my firebase real-time database but when i try to add the child node with the data i'm getting this error below. I tried to change the type of `userData` variable to `String` but nothind changed.

**The error:**

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : String?]' to expected argument type 'String'
```

**My Code:**

```
private func firebaseAuthentication(withUser user: GIDGoogleUser) {
    
  if let authentication = user.authentication {
    
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (_, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      } else {
        
        // Add user data to real-time db if user does not already exists
        let userData = [
            "id" : Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
            "email" : Auth.auth().currentUser?.email,
            "name" : Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName,
            "photoUrl": "none",
            "premium": "false"
        ]
        
                
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            
            if !snapshot.hasChild(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "noid") {
                // user does not exist
                
                usersRef.child(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "noid").child(userData) // here i'm getting the error
                
            }
            
        } withCancel: { error in
            
        }

        
        self.state = .signedIn
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
.child(userData)
```

with

```
.setValue(userData)
```